# Delay in continuosly writing to serial port

Tags: java, serial-port

I am writing "AT" commands to a GSM modem via an RS 232 serial port for sending messages.
I am doing so in a "for" loop and i need to know how to reduce the delay that i need to provide in the for loop for successfully sending messages.

The delay varies a lot, e.g for sending a message to 10 ppl a delay of 3800ms is enough, but for 200 recipients the delay needs to be increased to something like 9000ms.

Environment - Netbeans, javax.comm api, wavecom fastrack modem with baud rate - 115200[supported], RS232 serial port connection.

I'm doing something like --

```
 OutputStream os = serialPortInstance.getOutputStream();  
 String arrOfNumbers = {"872346334","23423433"};//I have the list of numbers here  
 String command = "";   
 for(int i = 0 ;i < arrOfNumbers.length ; i++){
     command = "AT+CMGS=\""+arrOfNumbers[i]+"\"\nHello" + ((char)26);
     os.write(command.getBytes());
     Thread.sleep(5000);  
 }
```

I want to minimize this delay.
Kindly help,
Thank you.

Comment: What affects the delay required? (How can it be figured out?)

Comment: The length of arrOfNumbers affects the delay required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay is superflous - the OutputStream will block until all the data has been written. Your *real* problem is probably that the device is busy after you send it a command and will abort the previous command if you send it another too soon.

That is avoided by checking the replies from the device. You need to also open an InputStream and *wait* for the reply from the device after each command. Consult the device manual on what possible replies it gives.

Comment: Yes. That did not solve the issue, but got the direction. "The modem's manual". The processing speed for the modem is significantly less than the speed at which the for-loop goes. (Big bad intel chip firing out loads of speed, comparatively). Good point @Durandal.

Answer (score 0):

This would make your for loop more efficient:

```
 final OutputStream os = serialPortInstance.getOutputStream();  
 final String arrOfNumbers = {"872346334","23423433"};//I have the list of numbers here
 final Byte[] commands = new Byte[arrOfNumbers.length];
 for(int i = 0 ;i < arrOfNumbers.length ; i++){
     final String commandString = "AT+CMGS=\""+arrOfNumbers[i]+"\"\nHello" + ((char)26);
     commands[i++] = commandString.getBytes(); 
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < arrOfNumber.length; i++) {
    os.write(commands[i]);
    os.flush();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cannot make the byte[] as final, Im using the same for assignment in the for loop, and afterwards.
I want to reduce the delay for sending messages actually, the code execution delay - I can afford for my case.

Comment: Ok my mistake you can leave the final out so: Byte[] commands = new Byte[arrOfNumbers.length]; but still this is preety much my answer with only that small correction. You want to decrese the 5 second delay? why have u got a 5 second delay then? That's an eternity any way.

Comment: true, according to the answer by Durandal - I referred the modem's manual. The modem's processing needs a bit of time for the process. Hence, the delay.